# React Native Android : index.android.bundle not updating on code change

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm having a new issue with Android on react-native and Android Studio, the App code does not update when I make change on my files.

I need to run 'react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/' and then run the app again on Android Studio so the app has the latest changes.

The hot reload works fine on IOS simulator but not the Android one.

I run on Mac OS 11 and the M1 emulator preview (https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview).

Any idea how I can fix this ?

Thanks in advance,
Julien

Answer (score -1):

I have sort of the same issue, I found this solution and it's worked for me.

Open `MainApplication.java` in the `android/app/src/main/java/{packagename}` directory ,delete the following code if exist

```
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
```

Change this method,

```
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
   // return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
   return true;
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.